# How to lengthen edge in forest to be the length of the edge label?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

How can I increase the length of the edges in a `forest` tree so that they are (at least) the length of the `edge label` that I wish to give them.

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{ew edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor = east, child anchor = west, grow' = east}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} ew edges
    [96
        [48, edge label = {node [midway, above, sloped] {matched place} }]
        [48, edge label = {node [midway, below, sloped] {unmatched place} }]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

produces the following tree

[image]

How can I make the edges (at least) the length of "unmatched place" so that there isn't such overlap?

Comment: Easiest is probably to adjust the `l sep` and/or `s sep` so that the children are spaced further from the parent/siblings. Not sure if I've really understood what you want to do, though.

Comment: @cfr That's true (and if you want to add that as an answer, that sounds great), but I was honestly hoping for some automagical way of doing things. Though perhaps that will be more of a pain than it's worth.

Comment: Note that the manual says 'The packing mechanism is not sensitive to edge labels.' on page 33.

Comment: @cfr Ah, I hadn't seen that. That's unfortunate. Hmm, maybe there is a way with `tikz-qtree`?

Comment: I've never used `tikz-qtree` although I did used to use `qtree`. Not sure whether either would do better? If your labels are not *terribly* long, you can calculate the distance and adjust things using `forest`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The packing system does not take account of edge labels, as explained on page 33. So the simplest way to do this is to adjust the minimum distance between levels (`l sep`) and/or the minimum distance between siblings (`s sep`) by hand.

For example, adding `s sep+=50pt` and `l sep+=50pt` to an expanded style, `ew edges new`, produces the following tree:

[image: adjusted tree]

Alternatively, it is possible to override the packing mechanism's decisions. To do this, you need to make adjustments after the packing stage but before the final positions are calculated. This can be done, for example, using `before computing xy`. Using a new style `my edge label` to adjust the distance between levels, for example, you can obtain a tree such as this:

[image: auto-adjusted levels]

This does require you to specify the edge label in a different way. Rather than specifying it using `edge label` directly, you need to use `my edge label`. (Obviously, you can use a different name - but you can't use `edge label`.) This is necessary because the new style manipulates the label to measure its width. This is then used to calculate an appropriate distance between the levels using Pythagoras' theorem.

Note that this second method cannot deal with labels which are *too* long because the dimensions involved in the calculation become too great. If you need to accommodate really long labels, you should probably adjust the calculation to minimise the sizes of the dimensions involved.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz, multi, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  ew edges new/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor = east,
      child anchor = west,
      grow' = east,
      s sep+=50pt,
      l sep+=50pt
    }
  },
  ew edges/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor = east,
      child anchor = west,
      grow' = east,
    }
  },
  my edge label/.style={
    if={n>.5*(n_children("!u"))}{
      edge label = {node [midway, below, sloped] {#1}},
    }{
      edge label = {node [midway, above, sloped] {#1}},
    },
    TeX={\settowidth{\mylabelwidth}{#1}},
    before computing xy={
      if={
        (l)<(sqrt((\mylabelwidth)^2 - s^2) + 10pt)
      }{
        l={sqrt((\mylabelwidth)^2 - s^2) + 10pt},
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\newlength{\mylabelwidth}
\begin{forest}
  ew edges new
    [96
      [48, edge label = {node [midway, above, sloped] {matched place} }
        ]
        [48, edge label = {node [midway, below, sloped] {unmatched place} }
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  ew edges
    [96
        [48, my edge label = matched place
        ]
        [48, my edge label = unmatched place
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer. `:)`